# open a binary file and prints all ASCII characters from that file

Tags: java, file, binary, ascii

I am trying to solve this problem.

> open a binary file and prints all ASCII characters from that
>   file, that is, all bytes with values between 32 and 126. Print a new line after every 64
>   characters

I came up with this code --

```
public String asciiRead()
 throws IOException
{
 FileInputStream fis = null; 
 try {
  fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
  int dataByte = 0;
  int count = 0;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  while (-1 != (dataByte = fis.read())) {
   if (32 <= dataByte && dataByte <= 126) {
     sb.append((char) dataByte);
   }  else if (0 == (count % 64)) {
     sb.append("\n");
   }
   count++;
  }

 } finally {
   if (null != fis) { fis.close(); }
 }
 return sb.toString();
}
```

I would like to know if my approach is correct.

Comment: Why not run it and find out?

Comment: You check for < 64 and not < 127, as you specify.

Comment: I run this...since I do not have much experience using java libraries so requesting to get this reviewed.

Comment: Why use else if? This block only gets executed, when the byte read is not an ASCII character. From what I understand, you want to append a newline after every 64 chars. Also, do you mean "after 64 chars read" or "after 64 ASCII chars"?

Comment: @mattes - you are right about the wrong use of else-if block here. second thing -- it was mentioned in the problem if it would be "after 64 character read" or "after 64 ASCII character read". I am assuming "after 64 ASCII character read" to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Way it worked for me.

```
while ((dataByte = fis.read())!=-1) {
if (32 <= dataByte && dataByte <= 126 )
{
   count++;
sb.append((char) dataByte);
if (0 == (count % 64)) {
sb.append("\n");count=0;
}

}  
}
```

What happening in your code `if(number or letter) than append , else if (check count)`

While we want `if(number or letter) than check is count==64 than append \n`.

You can see the difference.

I hope you got your answer.

Best Of Luck

Comment: The `else` has to be removed or every 64 characters one character will be missing. The `dataByte` has always to be appended.

Comment: count needs to be incremented inside the outer if block and before checking it for modulo 64. Otherwise you might end up without linefeeds, if every 64th char happens to not be an ASCII character.

Comment: Almost there :) remove the else block (including the count++) and move the first count++ before the second if. The way it is now, you add a new line after the 65th byte instead of the 64th ASCII char.